# Parallax image is not displayed properly on support lib 24.2.0

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-design-library

I just updated to the new support lib version 24.2.0 and experienced the following  problem with parallax images in a `CollapsingToolbarLayout`:

[image: 24.1.1]

How it looked like on `24.1.1`

[image: 24.2.0]

How it now looks like on `24.2.0`

This examples are from the [Cheesesquare](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare) demo app which I did not modify apart from the support lib version. [This](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare/blob/4dfeabfbd083e06d97c7d5ac851a00b8c0ebc792/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_detail.xml) is the relevant layout file.

It looks like the image is not properly overlaying the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` anymore.

Does anybody know what is causing this and/or how to fix it?

**Edit**

Fixed as of 24.2.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a bug and it was already reported https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=220389

**EDITED**

According to Chris Banes post

> The issue is that the ImageView is receiving the standard
>   View#fitSystemWindows padding. You can set the following on the
>   ImageView for a quick workaround:

```
ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(this, OnApplyWindowInsetsListener() {
    @Override
    public WindowInsetsCompat onApplyWindowInsets(View v,
            WindowInsetsCompat insets {
        return insets.consumeSystemWindowInsets();
    }
});
```

Comment: Yup, already saw that. I added some information; hopefully Google will fix this issue soon.

Comment: Any chance you guys CC @RubenGees have noticed this issue (https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=220570) with the CollapsingToolbarLayout's title not collapsing properly. I'm experiencing the same visual effects as described but I don't think the EditText problem described is what I'm experiencing, thanks in advance!

Comment: @ForrestBice i'm not sure if they are the same issue, but you can try this workaround, to see if you get it working.